# I have another TypeError in Python3.5

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, cpu, error-suppression

I'm making a module to implement the basics of a computer and emulate so stuff, but in a specific part of the code handling the memory - Python Gives me an error i can't seem to fix...

Here's the code for computer.py:

```
def nop():
    nop = 'nop'

class Computer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Started = True

    def Boot(self, RAM, OS, MemoryObj, Memory, CPU):
        self.RAM = RAM
        self.Memory = Memory
        self.CPU = CPU

        MemoryObj.addMem(OS, Memory, 0)

        if len(Memory) < 1000:
            diffrence = 1000 - len(Memory)
            for x in range(diffrence):
                MemoryObj.addMem('d')
        else:
            nop()

        MemoryObj.addMem(RAM, Memory, 1000)

        CPU.start()




class Memory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Memory = []
        self.Address = []
        for x in range(5096):
            self.Memory.append('0')
            self.Address.append(x)

    def addMem(self, data, Memory, lastAddr):
        LenData = len(data)

        for x in range(LenData):
            Memory.insert(data[x], x + lastAddr)

    def GetMemByte(self, Memory, addr):
        return(Memory[addr])

    def GetMemLen(self, Memory, length, startaddr):
        for x in range(length):
            byte = self.GetMemByte(Memory, startaddr + x)
            if byte == ' ':
                GetMem = GetMem + '-'
            elif byte == ';':
                GetMem = GetMem + 's'
            else:
                GetMem = GetMem + byte
         return(GetMem)


class CPU:
    def __init__(self):
        self.codes = {
            'shw': 'print'
        }

    def start(self, MemoryObj, Memory):
        OSCODE = MemoryObj.GetMemLen(Memory, 1000, 0)

        self.execute(OSCODE)

    def execute(self, Code):
        codebase = self.codes

        _temp = ''


        while True:
            for x in range(len(Code)):
                if Code[x] == 's':
                    lengoto = x
                    break
                else:
                    _temp = _temp + Code[x]
            if lengoto == len(Code):
                break
            else:
                _temp.split('-')
                func = _temp[0]

                ourfunc = codebase[func]

                pystring = ourfunc

                varable = _temp[1]

                pystring = pystring + varable

                exec(pystring)
```

Heres the code for Test.py:

```
import computer

comp = computer.Computer()

mem = computer.Memory()

cpu = computer.CPU()

comp.Boot('', 'shw (\'How are you doing?\')', mem, mem.Memory, cpu)
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/root/Documents/Test1.py", line 9, in <module>
    comp.Boot('', 'shw (\'How are you doing?\')', mem, mem.Memory, cpu)
  File "/private/var/root/Documents/computer.py", line 13, in Boot
    MemoryObj.addMem(OS, Memory, 0)
  File "/private/var/root/Documents/computer.py", line 41, in addMem
     Memory.insert(data[x], x + lastAddr)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: `data[x]` is a string. `Memory` is a list. `list.insert` requires an integer as its first argument.

Comment: I’m super confused by you mixing up the type `Memory`, with the property `Memory` on `computer`, with the property `Memory` on the `Memory` type, and with the `Memory` variable you keep passing into methods of the `Memory` type (instead of referring to the current instance using `self`). Do you know what you are doing there? Then please rename all those variables so that they make more sense (e.g. non-types shouldn’t be title cased).